# 3 Table, SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that pulls from 3 tables and haven't been able to achieve the results I need. I want to return all the property names (labels) that are paired with a particular category and pair those properties with the values from a particular asset from the said category, which may not have a value to pair with each property.

I want *all* the properties for **category 4**, paired with the values for **asset 135**. Asset 135 doesn't have values set for property 3 or 4, so I want:

```
| property_name | property_value     |  
|:--------------|:-------------------|  
| Fixture ID    | A5                 |  
| Manufacturer  | Black & Decker     |  
| Model #       |                    |  
| Type          |                    |
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT property.property_name, asset_property.property_value
FROM property
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_property
ON property.property_id = category_property.property_id
INNER JOIN asset_property
ON asset_property.property_id = property.property_id
WHERE category_property.category_id = 4
AND asset_property.asset_id = 135
```

**resulting data**:

```
| property_name | property_value     |  
|:--------------|:-------------------|  
| Fixture ID    | A5                 |  
| Manufacturer  | Black & Decker     |
```

It's missing 2 of the properties because of my `AND asset_property.asset_id = 135`

Here are the **tables**:
* asterisk just indicates rows from test case.

table: **property**

```
| property_id | property_name |  
|:-----------:|:--------------|  
| 1           | Fixture ID    |*  
| 2           | Manufacturer  |*  
| 3           | Model #       |*  
| 4           | Type          |*  
| 5           | Lamp Type     |
```

table: **asset_property**
pairs assets with property values.

```
| asset_id | property_id | property_value |  
|:--------:|:-----------:|:---------------|
| 129      | 1           | A5             |  
| 129      | 2           | Black & Decker |  
| 129      | 3           | 1230-02        |  
| 129      | 4           | Incandescent   |  
| 135      | 1           | E6             |*  
| 135      | 2           | Linden         |*  
| 147      | 1           | G1             |
```

table: **category_property**
pairs categories with its properties.

```
| category_id | property_id |  
|:-----------:|:-----------:|  
| 4           | 1           |*  
| 4           | 2           |*  
| 4           | 3           |*  
| 4           | 4           |*  
| 7           | 2           |  
| 7           | 5           |
```

I've tried all the different JOIN types, HAVING, GROUP BY....can't it figure out. If anyone understand what I need, I'd really appreciate the help! Thanks!

---

To clarify, I need to return these sets of results:

```
| property_name |  
|:--------------|  
| Fixture ID    |  
| Manufacturer  |  
| Model #       |  
| Type          |
```

AND

```
| property_value |  
|:---------------|  
| A5             |  
| Black & Decker |
```

And join them on `property_id`:

```
| property_name | property_value |  
|:--------------|:---------------|  
| Fixture ID    | A5             |  
| Manufacturer  | Black & Decker |  
| Model #       |  
| Type          |
```

But since there is no record for `property_id` 4 and 5 in the `asset_property table`, the `property_name` for those properties aren't shown.

```
| property_name | property_value |  
|:--------------|:---------------|  
| Fixture ID    | A5             |  
| Manufacturer  | Black & Decker |
```

<del>Model #

Type</del>

I want them to e shown. I want *ALL* the property names for **Category 4** to be returned and be paired with any matching property_values for **Asset 135**.

---

So for the **Fruits Category** I want all the properties names returned (Color, Season, Taste). The color property for Apple is not set, but I still want all the property types to be returned, so they can be changed or filled out:

```
| property_name | property_value |  
|:--------------|:---------------|  
| Color         |                |  
| Season        | Fall           |  
| Taste         | Tart           |
```

Comment: The result you want is one pivot away from being a normalized table. If you can, consider normalizing your schema, it makes querying much simpler. This schema looks like Magento's to me, which you have no control over, but if it's custom, you could save yourself some work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and move `AND asset_property.asset_id = 135` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT property.property_name,
       asset_property.property_value
  FROM property
 INNER
  JOIN category_property
    ON property.property_id = category_property.property_id
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN asset_property
    ON asset_property.property_id = property.property_id
   AND asset_property.asset_id = 135
 WHERE category_property.category_id = 4
;
```

(I've also changed the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, since the `WHERE category_property.category_id = 4` will (correctly) filter out records where the join fails, anyway.)

Comment: If I added a row to asset_property and left the asset_id *NULL*, the **OR** statement kicks in, but I need *ALL* the matches from `WHERE category_property.category_id = 4` and fill in the results from `assed_id = 135`, but not limit them.

Comment: @flackend: Interesting! In Oracle, both of the options that I mentioned are options that work (I tested), but it turns out that in MySQL (and PostgreSQL, and possibly other DMBSes) only one of them works. I've edited my answer to remove mention of the option that doesn't work in MySQL. Sorry about that!